# Netbeans c++ memory leaks

Tags: c++, netbeans

Is there anybody who knows how can I get to know is there are memory leaks using netbeans IDE? My code is written in c++.I tried to use valgrind but it does not work.

Provided I got a an app and im going to build/Debug/GNU-Linux and there is no exec which I could test with valgrind.
I will appreciate any sort of help.

I tried to use Profile but still I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Development tools are better suited for [so] but as it stands your question is likely to be closed if we migrate it there. When you use any of these tools what happens? What output do you get?

Comment: Its not clear if your asking for help to find memory leaks in Netbeans or your own application.  What makes you think your code has memory leaks in the first place?

Comment: I just want to check whether it got memory leaks.( it uses some pointers that is why i want to check it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself.

1.If you want to use valgrind firstly you should compile your project in release mode

2.then go to directory where your app is released.

3.Open the terminal and test your app ;)